# onUpdate cloud function is not working with firestore data

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i have a firestore collection where i have a field like category with few values like category 1, category 2. I have a cloud function which is getting me the total count and duration of category 1 and category 2.

This function is working fine for create. But when i update it, count is getting updated but duration is not. This is my update function;

```
export const updateDuration = 
functions.firestore.document('Duration/{userId}/Duration/{uid}')
.onUpdate(async(change, context) => {
const oldData = change.before.data();

const newData = change.after.data();

const Duration = newData.WorkDuration;

if (newData.WorkDuration == oldData.WorkDuration) {
   return null } else {
    const Ref = newData.parent!
    Ref.set({
     Duration: Duration
    })
    
   }

   return null

  


})
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell us what this duration does exactly? Is it a field in collections or is it measuring something? If it is possible can you also please share your DB structure with us?

Answer (score 1):

The `return null` probably terminates function before the `set()` promise is resolved. Try this:

```
export const updateDuration = 
functions.firestore.document('Duration/{userId}/Duration/{uid}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
  const oldData = change.before.data();
  const newData = change.after.data();

  const Duration = newData.WorkDuration;

  if (newData.WorkDuration == oldData.WorkDuration) {
    return null 
  } else {
    const Ref = newData.parent!
    return Ref.set({ // add return here
      Duration: Duration
    }) 
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but when i do that i get error while deploying the function error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.